# Works on Linux, crash on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, crash, command-line-arguments

I've written a program which has a class which is supposed to copy a string from the command line arguments.

Here is the offending piece of code.

```
void FileHandler::SetFile(const char*& filename)
{
    for(unsigned tsr = 0; tsr < 200; tsr ++){
        if(filename[tsr] == 0x0){
            mFilename = new char[tsr];
            strcpy(mFilename, filename);
            mFilenameAllocated = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I assume an command argument is NULL terminated, and so this block of code looks for a NULL character to find the length of the string, before memcpy'ing it into some new memory space.

What have I overlooked? Or should this code "just work"?

Thanks

EDIT:

Is it fault with strcpy? If command arg's aren't NULL terminated, will it just run along a section of memory until it causes an access violation?

Comment: If this is C++, why do it the hard way? Use `std::string`.

Comment: What if your string is less than 200 characters, should it not crash either way, you are iterating past the end of string

Comment: Yes, 200 is just a 'crazy' upper limit, which will never be exceeded.

Comment: @RobGoodwin, Your point holds, but remember that it doesn't have to crash if it doesn't want to.

Comment: @EdwardBird What we are saying is that it should always crash unless it is 200, you got lucky on Linux

Comment: @chris Would it have been better to say "Undefined" behavior?

Comment: Why will it crash unless the string is 200 chars long?

Comment: @RobGoodwin, Yes, that's what out-of-bounds access is.

Comment: @EdwardBird, You check for a null character, but once you find it, you keep iterating.

Comment: @chris - Fair enough - I see the error in my wording

Comment: Oh dear I was very tired when I wrote this code...

Comment: Even if you have to use C-style string manipulation, you can simplify this by eliminating the loop+'if' and by simply using `tsr = strlen(filename) + 1;`.  You are essentially re-implementing the standard `strlen()` function.

Comment: Okay thanks i did not know about strlen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1:

The for loop does not 'break' after a NULL character is found. This means sometimes it will exhibit undefined behavior. (This is a problem when coding for too long.)

Problem 2:

The memory allocation is 1 character two short.

EDIT:

Contributors have been +1 upped.

Answer (score 3):

Your allocated string is one character too short.

Imagine the input is `"A"`. You will then find the `0x0` at index 1, and allocate one char. `strcpy` will then copy the A and the null terminator and you are doomed.

Comment: You're also not returning from the function after making the string. You're always going to be going to 200 characters, and you could find more null characters.

Comment: @Falmarri very true. Seems like I am bad at finding the more obvious bugs :(